Timeout Error - Python script to update AGOL attributes
I'm trying to build a python script that will update attributes on feature layers on AGOL, end goal would be to have scheduled tasks to update the attributes nightly (without effecting geometry). My attribute update file is a csv with approximately 9000 row and about 6 columns. Every time I run the full csv file I run into a timeout error. I have reduced the file to 3 columns and still occasionally get the timeout error. I'm newer to python so I wouldn't be surprised if this is a horribly inefficient way to complete this task.
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

try:
    # Connect to ArcGIS Online
    gis = GIS('', 'UN', 'PW', expiration=9999)
    logging.info("Successfully connected to ArcGIS Online.")

    # Access the feature layer, use the polygon layer service url not feature layer
    layer_url = "layer url"
    feature_layer = FeatureLayer(layer_url)
    logging.info("Successfully accessed the feature layer.")

    # Read the CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv('updates.csv')
    updates_df = df.fillna(value=0)
    logging.info("Successfully read the CSV/xlsx file.")

    # Define the identifier field used in your CSV and feature layer
    csv_id_field = 'apprid'  # Identifier in CSV file
    layer_id_field = 'apprid'  # Corresponding field in feature layer

    # Query the feature layer to get all features
    query_result = feature_layer.query(where="1=1")#, out_fields="*")
    #logging.info(f"Full query result: {query_result}")
    logging.info(f"Query successful: {query_result}")

    # Check if 'features' key is present in the query result
    if not query_result.features:
        logging.error("Query result does not contain features. Check the layer URL and query parameters.")
        raise KeyError("Query result does not contain features")

    features = query_result.features
    logging.info(f"Successfully queried the feature layer. Number of features retrieved: {len(features)}")

    # Prepare updates based on the CSV file
    updates = []
    for feature in features:
        feature_id = feature.attributes[layer_id_field]
        update_row = updates_df[updates_df[csv_id_field] == feature_id]
        if not update_row.empty:
            updated_attributes = {"apprid": feature.attributes["apprid"]}
            for column in updates_df.columns:
                if column != csv_id_field:
                    updated_attributes[column] = update_row[column].values[0]
            updates.append({"attributes": updated_attributes})
        else:
            logging.warning(f"No update found for feature_id: {feature_id}")

    # Apply the attribute updates
    if updates:
        update_result = feature_layer.edit_features(updates=updates)
        logging.info(f"Updates Complete")
    else:
        logging.info("No updates to apply.")

except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

Saw something on another chain to add expiration = 9999 to my GIS connection. This didn't seem to make a difference.
gis = GIS('', 'UN', 'PW', expiration=9999)


Couple of questions and suggestions:

Is there a reason why you need to loop through all the rows and each of their columns? 9000 features is a lot to process through. Consider breaking down the batches to 100s of rows instead of breaking them by columns.

Is it possible to only update rows that's updated? This might require a bit of joins and finding differences between two datasets. Perhaps this would give you an idea:
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/python-api-how-to-update-feature-layer-attributes/td-p/867767

Is overwriting the feature layer with an updated CSV possible? A bit of a brute method, but could be the easiest approach considering your dataset size:
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/samples/overwriting-feature-layers/#overwrite-the-feature-layer



Thanks for the reply! I like the idea of batches of 100s, and only updating the csv. I will look further into these community articles.  I don't think overwriting the feature layer with a csv will work for my application as I only want to change the attribute features, not geometry. If I understand that process correctly, I would need to export the csv, update it, and then overwrite the feature layer. My plan is to update feature layers frequently (nightly or weekly) and this will be one of several feature layer updates.
